# Count data in every month

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I've already research this in other question but I didn't get an answer so decide to ask here.

I have 2 tables which is the tblCourse and tblData, I have been storing all of my course list in tblCourse while in tblData I am storing the person name and what course they took. Now, what I want to do is, I want to get the total count of all the person who are taking a particular course in every month.

For example:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Course  | Jan | feb | Mar | Apr | May | ......................| Dec | Total |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Course1 |  2  |  3  |  0  |  0  |  1  | ......................|  2  |   8   |    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Course2 |  2  |  3  |  2  |  0  |  1  | ......................|  2  |   10  |    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Course3 |  2  |  3  |  1  |  0  |  1  | ......................|  2  |   9   |    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's my code:

```
    <?php 
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblcourse where category = 'Soft' and inex = 'inhouse' ORDER by course_name ASC");


    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    ?>
         <tr>
         <td>Id</td>
         <td><?php echo $row->course_name; ?></td> // Output the Course Name
         <td class="center"><?php echo $row->days; ?></td> //Output the Training days

<?php 
$course = $row->course_name;    
$query_jan = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbldata where course like '%$course%' and course_end < '2016-11-30' and course_end >= '2016-11-01'");

?>

<td><?php echo $query_jan->num_rows(); ?></td> // Output the corresponding number of course taken by the person for the month of january

<? php
} // end of foreach
?>
```

Here's the structure of my database:

```
Table 1: tblCourse
Fields: ID, Course_name, Category, Training_days

Table 2: tblData
Fields: ID, Trainees_name, Course_taken, Date_start, Date_end
```

I'm just starting to develop using php.

Can I query this in a single query?

Comment: What is the relationship between `tblCourse` and `tblData`? If you have a relationship, then you could perform an SQL-JOIN and get the result you want...

Comment: can you show me how? lets assume that course_taken is the foreign key from  tbldata

Answer (score 0):

Considering `Course_taken` as foreign key to table `tblCourse`.

```
select tblCourse.Course_name,
       Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,(Jan+Feb+Mar+Apr+May+Jun+Jul+Aug+Sep+Oct+Nov+Dec) as `Total`    
from (
    select 
    tblCourse.Course_name+

        sum(CASE WHEN month(tblData.Date_start)=1 or month(tblData.Date_end)=1  THEN 1 else 0 end) as `Jan`,
        sum(CASE WHEN month(tblData.Date_start)=2 or month(tblData.Date_end)=2  THEN 1 else 0 end) as `Feb`,
        sum(CASE WHEN month(tblData.Date_start)=3 or month(tblData.Date_end)=3  THEN 1 else 0 end) as `Mar`,
        sum(CASE WHEN month(tblData.Date_start)=4 or month(tblData.Date_end)=4  THEN 1 else 0 end) as `Apr`,
        sum(CASE WHEN month(tblData.Date_start)=5 or month(tblData.Date_end)=5  THEN 1 else 0 end) as `May`,
        sum(CASE WHEN month(tblData.Date_start)=6 or month(tblData.Date_end)=6  THEN 1 else 0 end) as `Jun`,

        sum(CASE WHEN month(tblData.Date_start)=7 or month(tblData.Date_end)=7  THEN 1 else 0 end) as `Jul`,
        sum(CASE WHEN month(tblData.Date_start)=8 or month(tblData.Date_end)=8  THEN 1 else 0 end) as `Aug`,
        sum(CASE WHEN month(tblData.Date_start)=9 or month(tblData.Date_end)=9  THEN 1 else 0 end) as `Sep`,
        sum(CASE WHEN month(tblData.Date_start)=10 or month(tblData.Date_end)=10 THEN 1 else 0 end) as `Oct`,
        sum(CASE WHEN month(tblData.Date_start)=11 or month(tblData.Date_end)=11 THEN 1 else 0 end) as `Nov`,
        sum(CASE WHEN month(tblData.Date_start)=12 or month(tblData.Date_end)=12 THEN 1 else 0 end) as `Dec`

    from tblCourse
    left join tblData on tblCourse.id=tblData.Course_taken
    group by tblCourse.id
) data
```

Note : Make sure `Date_start` and `Date_end` should be of same year.

Comment: hi, I try your query but there is a error I paste the query above so you can easily seen the query. Hoping for your answer..

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(Trainees_name) FROM tbldata where Course_taken like '%$course%' and Date_start < '2016-11-30' and Date_end >= '2016-11-01'"
```